# Data loads with preset symbology in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, representation, default

I have a set of points in a file gdb.  When I load them in ArcMap or ArcCatalog, the data displays with unique value symbology based on a field rather than "single symbol".  How do I get the data to load with single symbol by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a subtype or domain set in your feature class (subtype) or geodatabase (domain)...

Comment: You can keep the subtype, just create an lyr file with single symbol. Then load it instead of the db

Comment: But there's no way to keep the subtype in the gdb and have the data load in single symbol, right?

Comment: Not that I know of...you might want to check on the ArcGIS support forum: http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/32-Geodatabase-amp-ArcSDE

Comment: How about creating a [Cartographic Representation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//008t00000002000000.htm) in "single symbol" mode for the default line style?  _"Symbolizing layers with representations -- When a feature class has a representation, you can use it to draw its features in a layer in ArcMap. When you add the feature class to a map, it will be drawn with the representation by default."_